# Need the following UI in Swing

Tags: java, swing

[image]
I need the following UI on JFrame. Two Jlabel Vertically Left aligned. Two button horizontally below the Jlabel. I tried below code but it is coming in one row.

> Label should be left and vertically aligned.
> Button should cover all the width of Jframe.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CustomPanel {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel basePanel= new JPanel();
    public static void main(String []args){
       CustomPanel cp= new CustomPanel();
       cp.showUI();
    }
    private void addui(){

        JPanel  labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label11 = new JLabel("I am here to test");
        JLabel label12 = new JLabel("I am here to test row");
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        labelPanel.add(label11, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;

        labelPanel.add(label12, gbc);
        basePanel.add(labelPanel);


        /////////////// button panel//////////
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
        panel.add(new JButton("Click me"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Click me22"));
        basePanel.add(panel);


    }
    private void showUI(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        addui();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setType(Window.Type.UTILITY);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(basePanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean: it comes out in one row?

Comment: labels and button are coming horizontal to each other.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

When creating a Swing GUI, you can break up a complex `JPanel` layout into more than one simpler `JPanels`.  I created three `JPanels` for this GUI; the main `JPanel`, the label `JPanel`, and the button `JPanel`.

[image]

A Swing application must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created the `JFrame` and the three `JPanels` in separate methods.  This allows me to focus on one part of the GUI at a time and makes the code much easier to read and follow.  This also allows me to experiment with different Swing layout managers to see which one is appropriate for the GUI.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CustomPanel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CustomPanel());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        panel.add(createLabelPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createLabelPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label11 = new JLabel("I am here to test");
        panel.add(label11, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel label12 = new JLabel("I am here to test row");
        panel.add(label12, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        panel.add(button);

        button = new JButton("Click me22");
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes , it is showing the result. But in case size of the frame is big button are coming to bottom due to (panel.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Comment: @vishal: And what's the whitespace under the buttons for?

Comment: Thanks for the help. White space will be used to show more data at runtime. and in case there is no data we still need to show frame size big enough.

Comment: @vishal: In that case, you add a JTextArea inside a JScrollPane.  Since that wasn't clear in the picture, I didn't include that.